# Basis for the space of quadratic polynomials orthogonal to those with $p(2)=p(1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, polynomials, inner-products

Let $P_2[x]$ be the space of polynomials
of degree less than or equal to 2. If $W = \{p ∈ P_2[x] \mid p(2) = p(1)\}$,
then find a basis for $ W^⊥$ where $P_2[x]$ is equipped with an inner product
given by $\langle p, q \rangle= \int^1_0p(x)q(x)dx$

My solution:
If $ax^2+bx+c \in P$ with  $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$
I have calculated the integrals
\begin{align*}
\frac{-11a}{20}+\frac{-3b}{4}+\frac{-7c}{6} &= 0\\
\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{4}+c &= 0
\end{align*}

Then what should I do?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: finding a basis @flawr

Comment: What do you mean when you say you've calculated the integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Start by calculating a basis for $W$.  I assume you can do this so lets just take $p_1$ and $p_2$ to be the basis elements that you've found (yes, there will be two of them).

Now take the polynomial $f = ax^2 + bx + c$.  You want to figure out conditions on $a, b, c$ such that $f \in W^\perp$.  This will allow you to describe $W^\perp$ as a subspace and then you can find a basis for it just like you found a basis for $W$.

So, since $p_1$ and $p_2$ are a basis for $W$, we have $f \in W^\perp$ if and only if $\langle f, p_1\rangle = 0$ and $\langle f, p_2\rangle = 0$.  So compute those two integrals and set them equal to zero.  This gives you a system of two equations in the variables $a, b, c$.  Solve those equations to get the conditions that give $f \in W^\perp$.